Is there a way to display the underscore in a footnote RTF file?
I am trying to display the underscore symbol in a footnote of rtf file using the r2rtf package, however, it is not showing. I tried to write "\\_" but it does not work.
# Load the necessary library
library(dplyr)
library(r2rtf)

# Specify the URL of the image
image_url <- "https://images.vexels.com/content/129159/preview/2d-colorful-bar-chart-infographic-9e35d8.png"

# Define the filename for saving
image_filename <- "bar_chart.png"

# Download the image
download.file(image_url, image_filename, mode = "wb")

# Confirm the file has been created
if (file.exists(image_filename)) {
  cat("Image saved as 'bar_chart.png' in the working directory.\n")
} else {
  cat("Failed to save the image.\n")
}

filename2 <- paste0(getwd(), "/bar_chart.png")


title2 <- "Figure 18.2: Proportion of patients achieving ESC/EAS and NICE guideline recommended LDL-C goals at baseline and 1-year follow-up (LDL-C dataset)"
filename2 %>%
  r2rtf::rtf_read_figure() %>%
  r2rtf::rtf_page(orientation = "landscape", margin = c(1, 1, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25)) %>% 
  r2rtf::rtf_page_header(text ="Data Base Lock date: FINAL",
                         text_font_size = 8, text_font = 9, text_justification = "l") %>%
  r2rtf::rtf_page_footer(text = "R program: p_figure_18_x_barchart.R     Production date: 10OCT2024                                 Page \\pagenumber of \\pagefield",
                         text_font_size = 8, text_font = 8, text_justification = "l") %>%
  r2rtf::rtf_title(title = title2,
                   text_font_size = 8, text_font = 9, text_justification = "l",
                   text_indent_left = 0, text_indent_reference = "page_margin") %>%
  r2rtf::rtf_figure(fig_width = 9, fig_height = 4.5) %>%
  r2rtf::rtf_encode(doc_type = "figure") %>%
  r2rtf::write_rtf(file = paste0(mypath, "p_figure_18_2_barchart.rtf"))

This code result in footnote:
Result 1
After I replace
r2rtf::rtf_page_footer(text = "R program: p_figure_18_x_barchart.R     Production date: 10OCT2024                                 Page \\pagenumber of \\pagefield"

by
r2rtf::rtf_page_footer(text = "R program: p\\_figure\\_18\\_x\\_barchart.R     Production date: 10OCT2024                                 Page \\pagenumber of \\pagefield"

Result:
Result 2
Is there a way to display the underscore with r2rtf package or any other package?
Thanks for your support.
